# jhipster could not found on the system console?

Tags: java, installation, ide, version, jhipster

When i perform `jhipster --version` in the command line i receive the following error on the console.

command executed:-
$ jhipster --version

Result :- bash: jhipster: command not found

someone please suggest what could be the po0ssible reasons behind this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `PATH` environment variable is wrong or that you did not restart bash after installing jhipster with `npm install -g generator-jhipster`